# How to update the value of a tooltip reading from a SVG element using onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

[image]I have a portion of a map where I want to change the value of the tooltip using a javascript function on triggering the onclick event of a button. Following is my code,

SVG:

```
<path
class="enabled"
fill="#FF822A"
 id="6"
 title="Orange County"
description="-"
 d="m 196.013,447.57347 0.355,-0.58737 -0.992,-0.69115 0.747,-1.51426 -0.613,-0.21057 1.241,-0.39998 -0.817,-0.39594 0.635,-0.45035 0.514,0.21157 -0.079,-1.62207 1.079,-0.11284 0.183,0.56218 1.652,-0.60953 -0.076,-2.68095 0.518,-0.68913 0.603,0.50879 1.068,-2.73032 2.201,-0.32844 -1.277,-1.91022 -0.86,-0.0615 0.277,-0.90775 -0.859,0.0625 0.093,-0.72942 -1.042,0.0211 -0.208,-1.04578 0.089,-0.74252 0.744,0.23777 0.114,-1.12336 0.952,0.26295 -0.357,-1.01052 0.572,-1.00145 -0.248,-0.35967 0.436,-1.29363 0.803,-0.26598 -0.917,-0.37479 -0.022,-0.39998 1.843,-0.87047 2.027,1.56464 0.113,0.64581 0.651,-0.28916 1.838,0.41006 0.567,-2.11978 -0.313,-1.77722 2.652,-0.99339 -0.623,-2.26385 0.671,-0.30225 -0.004,-0.72036 -0.864,-1.31277 0.337,-0.5914 1.245,-0.53196 0.47,-1.50318 -0.602,-1.29564 -0.939,-0.23072 0.532,-1.46994 0.35,0.72036 1.003,0.0876 0.282,0.95511 1.644,0.44632 0.372,0.51786 0.677,-0.63574 1.62,0.0937 2.361,1.12941 1.432,-0.26699 1.272,0.45438 0.276,2.27191 1.196,-0.25389 1.109,0.41206 0.243,1.42763 -0.544,0.74051 0.802,-0.2277 0.534,0.49166 1.769,0.26598 1.568,1.49714 0.945,-0.15818 -0.337,-0.53095 0.624,-0.78181 0.152,-1.9072 1.276,0.49871 0.197,0.54808 1.146,-0.12694 2.123,1.6402 1.512,-1.13545 0.206,0.63271 0.954,0.36169 0.872,-1.58378 2.106,-0.62566 0.944,0.21258 0.896,1.25938 2.344,1.61199 0.687,1.4115 -0.235,2.29911 -0.871,1.57875 0.482,1.23922 -1.782,1.47498 0.032,1.54147 1.183,-0.2821 0.385,0.56923 0.094,3.60785 -0.942,0.62263 0.796,1.02765 1.682,0.39091 2.061,2.00492 0.989,-0.43826 0.646,0.45136 0.271,-0.48461 1.374,-0.45337 0,0 1.556,2.91065 2.964,-0.92186 3.124,2.41598 0.379,1.02966 1.007,0.80096 -0.165,0.36875 0.744,0.2287 -0.215,0.57629 0.593,1.78226 0.911,1.06291 -1.148,0.77779 0.027,1.03973 1.326,0.1199 0.663,-1.49714 0.794,0.5924 -0.404,0.21259 0.289,1.43266 2.338,-0.78182 -0.622,1.9213 1.852,6.41876 0.861,0.0756 1.8,-1.46087 1.977,0.89164 2.741,0.1219 0,0 1.559,-0.39897 0.455,0.48159 1.833,-0.5511 0.888,0.27504 1.086,-1.35508 0.529,-0.17329 0.311,0.52088 1.154,-0.71029 0,0 0.722,0.8997 -0.218,0.45337 -4.307,2.33034 -0.114,0.84025 -1.428,2.15605 0.434,0.44329 -0.466,0.66697 -0.167,1.9898 -1.629,1.91626 -0.917,0.0967 -0.987,-0.73346 -1.204,1.55054 -1.792,-0.0494 -0.393,1.96864 -2.433,0.41106 -1.158,0.74958 -1.798,-0.47352 0.167,1.21302 -0.9,-0.008 -0.241,2.09358 -0.552,0.55211 -2.234,-0.85335 -1.803,0.20754 0.357,-0.71532 -2.02,-1.1022 -1.341,0.66092 -0.291,1.2634 -0.753,0.72943 -0.538,-0.17128 -0.533,-1.1566 -0.587,0.46042 0.454,0.93194 -0.638,0.95107 2.712,1.16669 0.074,-0.67402 1.944,0.47453 0.054,1.15258 -0.456,0.10679 -0.218,0.96921 1.037,0.81104 -0.864,0.54506 -2.228,-0.59443 -0.08,-0.55412 -1.107,-0.75361 -0.56,0.8463 -0.3,-0.96015 -0.824,-0.35161 -0.375,-1.85984 -0.82,-1.19993 -1.275,-0.0544 -0.401,-0.69819 -1.01,1.30672 -1.842,0.43927 -0.76,1.27146 -0.374,0.96418 0.867,0.23676 0.766,0.85033 -0.456,1.49915 -1.879,2.25579 -1.174,0.0927 -0.842,-1.32184 -1.08,0.16926 -0.741,-0.85436 -2.655,1.47699 -3.158,0.69014 -1.478,1.04981 -3.359,0.45942 -0.854,1.16467 -0.139,5.86766 -0.881,0.49166 -3.049,-0.62465 -2.207,0.94705 -0.42,0.44531 0.106,1.67446 -0.792,-0.10881 -0.204,-0.93697 -0.525,-0.0796 -0.028,1.51326 -1.287,1.39135 -1.284,-0.0655 -2.023,-1.57673 -1.213,0.9279 -3.212,-0.53598 -1.872,1.13041 -1.247,-0.0474 -0.391,2.22859 -1.213,0.62364 -0.322,1.12134 -0.813,0.001 -0.34,0.47453 -0.961,-0.37882 -0.574,-1.25332 -0.72,0.93395 -2.39,-0.79996 -1.852,0.66697 -1.74,-0.46345 -1.196,0.21963 -1.101,-0.76771 -2.029,-0.19848 0,0 0.014,-1.7742 -0.405,-0.6186 0.39,-1.59084 -0.475,-0.26699 -0.064,-0.93395 0.567,-1.41352 -0.459,-0.0222 -0.026,-0.55513 0.286,-0.39393 0.681,0.11284 0.654,-0.76469 0.53,0.23676 0.027,-1.10724 -2.033,-0.83622 -1.732,0.28613 -1.44,-0.37177 -1.22,-0.50879 -1.037,-1.42157 1.19,-0.12191 0.097,-0.3899 1.459,0.1612 0.267,-0.58133 0.758,-0.15616 -0.499,-1.03571 1.522,-0.41509 0.11,-1.37221 -0.763,0.20352 -0.343,-0.5511 1.014,-0.33852 0.038,-0.73749 -0.909,-0.0554 0.296,-1.50218 0.703,0.0876 -0.371,-2.84517 0.963,-2.15403 -0.77,-2.12078 -2.148,-1.26239 0.812,-1.03369 -0.386,-0.2418 1.552,-1.23217 -0.429,-0.27203 0.368,-1.80543 0.995,0.36068 0.605,-0.39594 0.157,-0.70223 -0.531,-0.50879 1.306,-0.0504 0.014,-0.54203 0.783,0.21963 0.007,-0.56521 0.617,-0.13298 0.258,-0.59947 -0.098,0.48461 0.752,0.18337 0.034,-0.72037 -1.965,-0.59442 -0.04,-0.66192 -0.867,0.29318 -0.44,-0.52289 -0.54,0.71129 -0.243,-0.55815 -1.048,-0.33349 0.218,-2.41698 2.338,-1.22713 0.082,-0.3758 -1.287,-0.40501 0.134,-0.41509 0.316,-0.55916 0.497,0.19344 0.482,-1.20698 0.502,0.0524 -0.241,-0.8322 0.656,0.11788 0.151,-1.209 0.424,0.25087 0.196,-0.50576 -0.151,-0.52592 -1.128,-0.37378 -0.974,-0.96216 1.148,-1.00649 -0.059,-1.1566 -0.7,-1.07299 0.81,-1.71073 z" />
```

JS:

```
    function tooltip_rank()
{
      var value = [ 
          "Winner",
          "2nd place",
          "6th place",
          "4th place",
          "3rd place",
          "5th place",
          "8th place",
          "7th plcae" ];
      var val;
      for(i=0;i<8;i++)
      {
         $('#'+i).attr("description",value[i]);

      }
    console.log(this.$value[0]);
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script  src="./tooltip_rank.js"></script>
</head>
<button class="button" class="enabled" onclick="tooltip_rank()">Change</button>
</html>
```

Here, I want to change the description value in the SVG file to the value present in the JS file. When I click the 2018 button, the tooltip visible on hover on that part should change to the value present in the array from the javascript file.

Comment: Seems like it should work although tooltips are title child elements in SVG rather than description attributes. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hey @RobertLongson, with this code nothing happens. I click the button and in the console window it shows the value[0] undefined. The function is responsive but it is not doing the expected job which is to replace the value of description in the SVG file using JS.

Comment: CSS doesn't really allow ids to be numeric. So something with id="6" is no good to you. Having said that, changing the description won't have any visible effect.

Comment: Is there any way I can make the tooltip text change ?

Answer (score 0):

This creates a child title element, in SVG those become tooltips.

Finding the county works because it doesn't use CSS to find the element. Having numeric ids is best avoided but if you must you can use getElementById to select them.

I fixed the console.log to be syntactically correct but I'm not sure what you really wanted it to print.

```js
    function tooltip_rank()
{
      var value = [ 
          "Winner",
          "2nd place",
          "6th place",
          "4th place",
          "3rd place",
          "5th place",
          "8th place",
          "7th plcae" ];
      var val;
      for(i=0;i<8;i++)
      {
         let county = document.getElementById(i);
         if (county) {
             let title = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "title");
             title.textContent = value[i];
             county.appendChild(title);
         }    
      }
    console.log(value[0]);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script  src="./tooltip_rank.js"></script>
</head>
<button class="button" class="enabled" onclick="tooltip_rank()">Change</button>
</html>
<svg viewBox="176 400 200 200">
<path
class="enabled"
fill="blue"
 id="6"
 title="Orange County"
description="-"
 d="m 196.013,447.57347 0.355,-0.58737 -0.992,-0.69115 0.747,-1.51426 -0.613,-0.21057 1.241,-0.39998 -0.817,-0.39594 0.635,-0.45035 0.514,0.21157 -0.079,-1.62207 1.079,-0.11284 0.183,0.56218 1.652,-0.60953 -0.076,-2.68095 0.518,-0.68913 0.603,0.50879 1.068,-2.73032 2.201,-0.32844 -1.277,-1.91022 -0.86,-0.0615 0.277,-0.90775 -0.859,0.0625 0.093,-0.72942 -1.042,0.0211 -0.208,-1.04578 0.089,-0.74252 0.744,0.23777 0.114,-1.12336 0.952,0.26295 -0.357,-1.01052 0.572,-1.00145 -0.248,-0.35967 0.436,-1.29363 0.803,-0.26598 -0.917,-0.37479 -0.022,-0.39998 1.843,-0.87047 2.027,1.56464 0.113,0.64581 0.651,-0.28916 1.838,0.41006 0.567,-2.11978 -0.313,-1.77722 2.652,-0.99339 -0.623,-2.26385 0.671,-0.30225 -0.004,-0.72036 -0.864,-1.31277 0.337,-0.5914 1.245,-0.53196 0.47,-1.50318 -0.602,-1.29564 -0.939,-0.23072 0.532,-1.46994 0.35,0.72036 1.003,0.0876 0.282,0.95511 1.644,0.44632 0.372,0.51786 0.677,-0.63574 1.62,0.0937 2.361,1.12941 1.432,-0.26699 1.272,0.45438 0.276,2.27191 1.196,-0.25389 1.109,0.41206 0.243,1.42763 -0.544,0.74051 0.802,-0.2277 0.534,0.49166 1.769,0.26598 1.568,1.49714 0.945,-0.15818 -0.337,-0.53095 0.624,-0.78181 0.152,-1.9072 1.276,0.49871 0.197,0.54808 1.146,-0.12694 2.123,1.6402 1.512,-1.13545 0.206,0.63271 0.954,0.36169 0.872,-1.58378 2.106,-0.62566 0.944,0.21258 0.896,1.25938 2.344,1.61199 0.687,1.4115 -0.235,2.29911 -0.871,1.57875 0.482,1.23922 -1.782,1.47498 0.032,1.54147 1.183,-0.2821 0.385,0.56923 0.094,3.60785 -0.942,0.62263 0.796,1.02765 1.682,0.39091 2.061,2.00492 0.989,-0.43826 0.646,0.45136 0.271,-0.48461 1.374,-0.45337 0,0 1.556,2.91065 2.964,-0.92186 3.124,2.41598 0.379,1.02966 1.007,0.80096 -0.165,0.36875 0.744,0.2287 -0.215,0.57629 0.593,1.78226 0.911,1.06291 -1.148,0.77779 0.027,1.03973 1.326,0.1199 0.663,-1.49714 0.794,0.5924 -0.404,0.21259 0.289,1.43266 2.338,-0.78182 -0.622,1.9213 1.852,6.41876 0.861,0.0756 1.8,-1.46087 1.977,0.89164 2.741,0.1219 0,0 1.559,-0.39897 0.455,0.48159 1.833,-0.5511 0.888,0.27504 1.086,-1.35508 0.529,-0.17329 0.311,0.52088 1.154,-0.71029 0,0 0.722,0.8997 -0.218,0.45337 -4.307,2.33034 -0.114,0.84025 -1.428,2.15605 0.434,0.44329 -0.466,0.66697 -0.167,1.9898 -1.629,1.91626 -0.917,0.0967 -0.987,-0.73346 -1.204,1.55054 -1.792,-0.0494 -0.393,1.96864 -2.433,0.41106 -1.158,0.74958 -1.798,-0.47352 0.167,1.21302 -0.9,-0.008 -0.241,2.09358 -0.552,0.55211 -2.234,-0.85335 -1.803,0.20754 0.357,-0.71532 -2.02,-1.1022 -1.341,0.66092 -0.291,1.2634 -0.753,0.72943 -0.538,-0.17128 -0.533,-1.1566 -0.587,0.46042 0.454,0.93194 -0.638,0.95107 2.712,1.16669 0.074,-0.67402 1.944,0.47453 0.054,1.15258 -0.456,0.10679 -0.218,0.96921 1.037,0.81104 -0.864,0.54506 -2.228,-0.59443 -0.08,-0.55412 -1.107,-0.75361 -0.56,0.8463 -0.3,-0.96015 -0.824,-0.35161 -0.375,-1.85984 -0.82,-1.19993 -1.275,-0.0544 -0.401,-0.69819 -1.01,1.30672 -1.842,0.43927 -0.76,1.27146 -0.374,0.96418 0.867,0.23676 0.766,0.85033 -0.456,1.49915 -1.879,2.25579 -1.174,0.0927 -0.842,-1.32184 -1.08,0.16926 -0.741,-0.85436 -2.655,1.47699 -3.158,0.69014 -1.478,1.04981 -3.359,0.45942 -0.854,1.16467 -0.139,5.86766 -0.881,0.49166 -3.049,-0.62465 -2.207,0.94705 -0.42,0.44531 0.106,1.67446 -0.792,-0.10881 -0.204,-0.93697 -0.525,-0.0796 -0.028,1.51326 -1.287,1.39135 -1.284,-0.0655 -2.023,-1.57673 -1.213,0.9279 -3.212,-0.53598 -1.872,1.13041 -1.247,-0.0474 -0.391,2.22859 -1.213,0.62364 -0.322,1.12134 -0.813,0.001 -0.34,0.47453 -0.961,-0.37882 -0.574,-1.25332 -0.72,0.93395 -2.39,-0.79996 -1.852,0.66697 -1.74,-0.46345 -1.196,0.21963 -1.101,-0.76771 -2.029,-0.19848 0,0 0.014,-1.7742 -0.405,-0.6186 0.39,-1.59084 -0.475,-0.26699 -0.064,-0.93395 0.567,-1.41352 -0.459,-0.0222 -0.026,-0.55513 0.286,-0.39393 0.681,0.11284 0.654,-0.76469 0.53,0.23676 0.027,-1.10724 -2.033,-0.83622 -1.732,0.28613 -1.44,-0.37177 -1.22,-0.50879 -1.037,-1.42157 1.19,-0.12191 0.097,-0.3899 1.459,0.1612 0.267,-0.58133 0.758,-0.15616 -0.499,-1.03571 1.522,-0.41509 0.11,-1.37221 -0.763,0.20352 -0.343,-0.5511 1.014,-0.33852 0.038,-0.73749 -0.909,-0.0554 0.296,-1.50218 0.703,0.0876 -0.371,-2.84517 0.963,-2.15403 -0.77,-2.12078 -2.148,-1.26239 0.812,-1.03369 -0.386,-0.2418 1.552,-1.23217 -0.429,-0.27203 0.368,-1.80543 0.995,0.36068 0.605,-0.39594 0.157,-0.70223 -0.531,-0.50879 1.306,-0.0504 0.014,-0.54203 0.783,0.21963 0.007,-0.56521 0.617,-0.13298 0.258,-0.59947 -0.098,0.48461 0.752,0.18337 0.034,-0.72037 -1.965,-0.59442 -0.04,-0.66192 -0.867,0.29318 -0.44,-0.52289 -0.54,0.71129 -0.243,-0.55815 -1.048,-0.33349 0.218,-2.41698 2.338,-1.22713 0.082,-0.3758 -1.287,-0.40501 0.134,-0.41509 0.316,-0.55916 0.497,0.19344 0.482,-1.20698 0.502,0.0524 -0.241,-0.8322 0.656,0.11788 0.151,-1.209 0.424,0.25087 0.196,-0.50576 -0.151,-0.52592 -1.128,-0.37378 -0.974,-0.96216 1.148,-1.00649 -0.059,-1.1566 -0.7,-1.07299 0.81,-1.71073 z" />


</svg>
```

Comment: Hi, edited my answer for better understanding. Hope it helps

Comment: Not really. As you can see with my answer after clicking on the button you get a tooltip so what's the issue now?

Comment: Didn't get it. No tooltip appeared only got the console output.

Comment: put the mouse over the shape after you click the change button.